# Declaring objects from one xib to another in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, declare

I have a project that has a switch from an xib separate from the main ViewController. I am trying to make it so that when you switch the UISwitch to OFF a button in the ViewController is hidden. I have tried to declare the AppDelegate in the xib's .m file but still no luck. My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

}

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to do

```
if (switch.on) {
     myButton.hidden = YES;
   } else {
     myButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

I have also done this in the .m file of the second xib (the one that does not have the main ViewController)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
```

But still NOTHING! So basically, I'm just trying to declare a button in one xib from another. THAT'S IT. PLEASE HELP Thanks!

Comment: is the second xib on the same story board? as in, both view controllers appear on the same storyboard screen, or is it a separate nib file that doesnt appear on the storyboard along with the viewcontroller?

Comment: @LuisOscar I am not using storyboard. In my Project folder, I have AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m, ViewController.xib, ViewnController.h, and ViewController.m. In my 2nd Folder for my 2nd xib, (I named it settings) settings.h, settings.m, and settings.xib what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

First, see [this about passing data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) and [this about UISwitch](http://www.xprogress.com/post-30-uiswitch-tutorial-example-how-to-use-the-switch-in-xcode-for-iphone-sample-included/).

Once you understand that, set up your code something like this--

FirstViewController.h:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
  ...
}
@property IBOutlet UISwitch *theSwitch;

- (IBAction)switchToggled;

@end
```

SecondViewController.h:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
  ...
}
@property IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property UIViewController *theFirstViewController;

@end
```

Be sure that `theFirstViewController` gets set somehow -- again, see [passing data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers). Then in `switchToggled` you can do this:

```
- (IBAction)switchToggled
{
  theFirstViewController.button.hidden = YES;
}
```

The important thing to remember is that your view controllers don't magically know about each other. Even if you do something with the AppDelegate like you were trying. `SecondViewController` needs a reference to `FirstViewController`.